# Get wordpress featured image url from another part of my site

Tags: php, mysql, image, wordpress

I have a Minecraft review website and let my reviewers produce content from this url SITEURL/content/

My website has wordpress installed on SITEURL/content/
I have coded my own site to display Wordpress posts on SITEURL
in no way is Wordpress installed on the main root directory, only on /content/

I have been able to grab posts from the Wordpress database and get them do display on the website I made http://minecraft-jar.net

Now, I need to (hook in) to Wordpress on the /content/ part and grab the featured image url from the post. I can get the ID of the post from a simple MySQL query and the variable is called $postID

Thanks.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it belongs on http://wordpress.stackexchange.com.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you would like to use Wordpress outside of the Wordpress framework you simply have to require the Wordpress blog header:

```
require('path/to/file/wp-blog-header.php');
```

You may also want to define the themes constant as false:

```
define('WP_USE_THEMES', false);
```

You can find more about integrating from the [Wordpress codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Integrating_WordPress_with_Your_Website).

Anyway, once you have your ID, simply do a [`get_the_post_thumbnail()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_post_thumbnail) and pass the ID as the argument and what size thumbnail you need. Make sure you do this after the `require` function.

Comment: Doesnt work, do you have skype, add me: darren2113

Comment: Are you getting an error? If you var_dump() the functions return value, is it giving you anything? Make sure your file path is the server side file path, not the client side.

Comment: No just a fatal error, if you could add me on skype we could talk it would be much easier

Comment: Can you post the error? I can't skype - at work :/

Comment: Fatal error: Call to undefined function get_the_post_thumbnail() in /home/darren95/public_html/search.php on line 42

Comment: http://minecraft-jar.net/search.php?cat=4

Comment: Ah, that just means that it's not finding the Wordpress blog header. Try this path: `require('/home/darren95/public_html/content/wp-blog-header.php');`

Comment: Great that worked. However, can i just get the url of the image and nnot an embeded img

Comment: Yup, just use this: `wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id($ID), 'full');`. Make sure to change the $ID variable to your stored variable.

Comment: Oh dear, now it thinks the variable is 'Array'

Comment: Yeah, that's because Wordpress can store multiple featured images. try this: 

`current( wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id($ID), 'full') );`

Comment: Great all fixed. However i do have another problem, if you add me on skype and chat (not call) it would be easier

Comment: You can the Wordpress room, I'm in there: http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/35933/wordpress

Comment: its saying that i must log in. I am logged in? what?